# Python regex. Report start,end of string blocks

Tags: python, regex

I'am struggling with python regex to get the correct output.

I have file with strings like this:

```
80H236M7I106M2885H
```

beside integers string can contain: IDMSH

I am trying to workout start end of certain parts in my string (parts of S and H. Those parts are always at the start,end or both ends of the string), the correct output for my example string would be:

```
0 80 80H236M7I106M2885H
429 3314 80H236M7I106M2885H
```

(basicaly we add up all numbers until we meet another block, we are searching for, end then we set up new start,end for it)
(btw would also be nice to know if the part is at the start or end of the string) eg:

```
0 80 80H236M7I106M2885H start
429 3314 80H236M7I106M2885H end
```

I used a code like this:

```
insstart = 0
insend = 0
for num1, i_or_d in re.findall('(\d+)([HISDM])', pcigar):
    if i_or_d in 'S':
        insstart == insstart
        insend += int(num1)
    elif i_or_d in 'H':
        insstart == insstart
        insend += int(num1)
    elif i_or_d in 'M':
        insstart += int(num1)
        insend += int(num1)
    elif i_or_d in 'I':
        insstart += int(num1)
        insend += int(num1)

    if i_or_d in 'H' or i_or_d in 'S':

        print insstart,insend,pcigar
```

### I didn't care about D, since in my file it wasn't present. However if somehow present, insstart, insend shouldn't be changed (==)

however it outputs:

```
0 80 80H236M7I106M2885H
349 3314 80H236M7I106M2885H
```

Can anyone help me out to get the correct output?
Cheers,
Irek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re

pcigar = "80H236M7I106M2885H"

insstart = 0
insend = 0
temp = 0

for num1, i_or_d in re.findall('(\d+)([HISDM])', pcigar):
    if i_or_d in 'S':
        insstart = insstart + temp
        insend += int(num1)
        temp += insend
    elif i_or_d in 'H':
        insstart = insstart + temp
        insend += int(num1)
        temp += insend
    elif i_or_d in 'M':
        insstart += int(num1)
        insend += int(num1)
    elif i_or_d in 'I':
        insstart += int(num1)
        insend += int(num1)

    if i_or_d in 'H' or i_or_d in 'S':

        print insstart, insend, pcigar
```